# import pandas Python3 on Synology DiskStation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, synology

my goal is to run a script on a Synology DiskStation using python3. I've installed Python 3 via the software center and tried to install Python pandas using pip. However, I'm having trouble with that.
Whenever I run as root

```
pip install pandas
```

i get

`File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Previously I had Python 2.7 running but uninstalled it and I have the feeling my problem might be related to the fact that I had two version of Python installed. But I'm not sure about it.

Variable **PYTHONHOME** is set to **/usr/local/python3**

Variable **PYTHONPATH** is set to **/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.4**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `pip` is usually an alias to the versioned `pip`, e.g. `pip2`. Have you tried `pip3 install pandas`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I get the same error message when I use `pip3`